# Socket multiple client one server

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client, tcpclient

How can I stop sending message to a client, while client do not read a message from server. To better understand what this means, consider a scenario in which a client does not call Read for an extended period of time, and server stops sending message to this client.
Server.cs receive message from client, and send to all clients

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket current = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int received;
            try
            {
                received = current.EndReceive(AR);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client forcefully disconnected");
                current.Close();
                clientSockets.Remove(current);
                return;
            }
            byte[] recBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, recBuf, received);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("Received Text: " + text);
            buffQueue.Enqueue(text);
            current.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, current);
            foreach (var client in clientSockets)
            {
                foreach (var msg in buffQueue)
                {
                    Sendata(client, text);
                }
                }
            }
       static void Sendata(Socket socket, string noidung)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(noidung);
            socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);

        }
        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);

        }
```

Client.cs

```
public void ReceiveMessage(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Socket socket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int received = socket.EndReceive(ar);
            byte[] dataBuf = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(receivedBuf, dataBuf, received);
            string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuf);
            Console.WriteLine("> " + msg + '\n');
            ClientSocket.BeginReceive(receivedBuf, 0, receivedBuf.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveMessage), ClientSocket);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that when a client does not read the buffer, the receivebuffer of the client will be full and the server will block in execution. You could prevent this by either:

- Queue the data for each client. The client must request data, so the server will send it's queue. (on a different thread)
- Use the `socket.Blocking = false` on the socket on the server. When the server is sending the data and the buffers are full, you'll get an WouldBlock exception or when using the right overload on sending, a SocketErrorCode is returned. [Windows Sockets: Blocking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tbz7kf5.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You still need a queue.

---

The `SendData` could be done parallel, because the bytebuffer/data doesn't change while sending.